# Bitmap index vs b-tree time complexity

Tags: database, indexing, bitmap, b-tree-index

Are queries on bitmap indexed fields with low distinct values faster in comparison with b-tree indices?

The common idea that bitmap indices give better query performance on fields with low distinct values in comparison with b-tree indices. But is it true?

For example, 
`SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE color = 'RED'`.
Here the `color` field has low distinct values and can be indexed with either b-tree or bitmap index:

- if `color` uses **b-tree** index, then for performing the query above, a database should do a binary search + in-order traversal (from the binary search result in both directions) which gives us O(log N + K) ~ O(log N) time complexity, where K - is the number of result rows. K <= N.
- if `color` uses **bitmap** index, then a database does a full scan which gives O(N) time complexity.

So, from my perspective, the bitmap index is even worse.
Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

In general your calculation is right. However, if fields have very few unique values, K is getting larger and close to N. Therefore `O(log N + K) ~ O(N)` holds.

Consider a query `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE gender='M' and marriage='YES'`. If M/F and YES/NO are equally distributed, this query leads to K=N/4 which is `O(N)`.

Additionally, although bitmap doesn't improve complexity a lot (both give the complexity of `O(N)` in this case), bitwise operation is way more faster than normal operation.